# how to use web service using EMF classes?

Tags: web-services, eclipse-emf

I want to create a web service by using classes created by EMF, as those classes are not in standard bean format, is there any wrapper or some tool available to create web service?

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of any such wrapper or tool.  But I'm puzzled why you would want to directly expose the EMF generated classes as a web service.  Wouldn't you end up with a web service API that is too fine grained to be practical?

Harking back to the world before EMF, one of the (valid) criticisms of the OMG MOF 1.x specs was that the MOF to CORBA IDL mapping gave interfaces that required too many requests to be made.  But in defence of MOF 1.x, CORBA IDL didn't get support for value types until CORBA 2.3, well after the MOF 1.x design was frozen.

People lost interest in using IDL after MOF 1.x.  By the time that the MOF guys started working on JMI, the preferred approach was to move models around as XMI blobs, and use the fine-grained APIs only for the in-memory deserializations.  And this is what JMI supported, and basically how EMF works as well.  (But with EMF you can also implement model persistence using other technologies; e.g. with Teneo.)